# Deploy Xamarin app with Microsoft intune

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, intune

I need some confirmation for the above. Recently, we have built an app using Xamarin and MvvmCross with Visual Studio 2013.

Now we are at the deployment stage. Is it possible to use Microsoft Intune for over the air deployment to Android devices?

Meaning, can we use Microsoft Intune to deploy a Xamarin based app to hundreds of Android devices through mobile network. Are there any known issues?

Will there be any issue with MvvmCross framework?

Comment: I haven't tried Intune. I know that HockeyApp among other services allow deploying to multiple devices without issues. Does Intune modify the apk in some way? If not I don't see there should be any issues whether you use X framework or not.

Comment: Just a quick check. Our app is for our customer only. we dont want to list our app in the appstore. it is for private consumption only. are you familiar with airwatch for xamarin app deployment? Thanks